# TYPO3 11.5 UploadFile Allowed File

Tags: forms, typo3

I have TYPO3 11.5.
I want to create a form with a input file field.
I have allowed Mime Types: "doc, docx, xls, xlsx, pdf, txt, odt, ods".

I want to add "zip" as  allowed Mime Type.

How i can do that?

I tried in my template setup:

```
//TEMPLATE FORM SETUP
plugin.tx_form.settings.yamlConfigurations {
   10002345234 = EXT:myext/Configuration/Yaml/FormElements/FileUpload.yaml      
}
```

and in my file yaml:

```
FileUpload:
  properties:
    containerClassAttribute: input
    elementClassAttribute: ''
    elementErrorClassAttribute: error
    saveToFileMount: '1:/user_upload/'
    allowedMimeTypes:
      - application/zip
```

Nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the correct code for template setup is:

```
//TEMPLATE FORM SETUP
module.tx_form.settings.yamlConfigurations {
   10002345234 = EXT:myext/Configuration/Yaml/FormElements/FileUpload.yaml      
}
```

and code for yaml:

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formElementsDefinition:
            FileUpload:
              formEditor:
                editors:              
                  300:
                    identifier: allowedMimeTypes
                    templateName: Inspector-MultiSelectEditor
                    label: formEditor.elements.FileUpload.editor.allowedMimeTypes.label
                    propertyPath: properties.allowedMimeTypes
                    selectOptions:
                      10:
                        value: application/msword
                        label: formEditor.elements.FileUpload.editor.allowedMimeTypes.doc
                      20:
                        value: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                        label: formEditor.elements.FileUpload.editor.allowedMimeTypes.docx
                      30:
                        value: application/msexcel
                        label: formEditor.elements.FileUpload.editor.allowedMimeTypes.xls
                      40:
                        value: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                        label: formEditor.elements.FileUpload.editor.allowedMimeTypes.xlsx
                      50:
                        value: application/pdf
                        label: formEditor.elements.FileUpload.editor.allowedMimeTypes.pdf
                      60:
                        value: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
                        label: formEditor.elements.FileUpload.editor.allowedMimeTypes.odt
                      70:
                        value: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template
                        label: formEditor.elements.FileUpload.editor.allowedMimeTypes.ods
                      80:
                        value: application/zip
                        label: 'zip' 
                properties:
                  containerClassAttribute: input
                  elementClassAttribute: ''
                  elementErrorClassAttribute: error
                  saveToFileMount: '1:/user_upload/'
                  allowedMimeTypes:
                    -   application/zip
```